# Put jPlayer playlist track in variable to reuse in multiple playlists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

This is the code I have now, it's the code for a playlist with two songs :

```
$("#audio-mix").click(function() {
    var playlistPoster = "img/playlist_poster.jpg";
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
        {
            title:"Song #01",
            artist:"Artist",
            mp3:"music/song_01.mp3",
            oga:"music/song_01.ogg",
            poster: playlistPoster
        },
        {
            title:"Song #02",
            artist:"Artist",
            mp3:"music/song_01.mp3",
            oga:"music/song_01.ogg",
            poster: playlistPoster
        }
    ]);
});
```

I added a variable playlistPoster so I don't have to write the link for the poster in every song.

But the same songs will be inserted in several other playlists with different order, new songs etc and I want to shorten the code.

I also want each playlist to have its unique "poster".

This code before the playlist worked :

```
var playlistPoster;
var song_01 = {
            title:"Song #01",
            artist:"Artist",
            mp3:"music/song_01.mp3",
            oga:"music/song_01.ogg",
            poster: playlistPoster
        }
```

But then I can't reset the playlistPoster variable for every playlist to display a different poster.

So I tried to put only this part in a variable :

```
        title:"Song #01",
        artist:"Artist",
        mp3:"music/song_01.mp3",
        oga:"music/song_01.ogg"
```

And that's my problem I tried to wrap it with quotes, use a backslash for multi-lines, and other tricks but I either get an error or an undefined playlist entry.

What's wrong ? :D Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me :

setting the variables :

```
var song_01 = {
        title:"Song #01",
        artist:"Artist",
        mp3:"music/song_01.mp3",
        oga:"music/song_01.ogg",
        poster: "img/default.jpg"
    }
var song_02 = {
        title:"Song #02",
        artist:"Artist",
        mp3:"music/song_02.mp3",
        oga:"music/song_02.ogg",
        poster: "img/default.jpg"
    }
```

The playlist code :

```
 $("#audio-mix").click(function() {
     myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
         song_01,
         song_02
     ]);
     document.getElementById("jp_poster_0").src = "playlist_poster.jpg"; // Change the poster image
 });
```